# problem with cck and cache

Tags: drupal, view, cck

i'm use Content Construction Kit (CCK) 6.x-2.9 and views ,boost for query of cck field my problem is many time field cck disable and noting show in field in my frontpage website when clear chache in admin/builds/performance cck feild is apear

please help me

thank you

Comment: can you enable any javascript console (like firebug) and reproduce you issue to see if there's any error is displayed on it?

Answer (score 0):

solved by clear cache and checked permision